Our cat scratched his head - do we need to go to a vet?
We have an indoors cat who has scratched his head a little bit a few days ago and then scratched the scab off earlier today, resulting in a bit of bleeding.
His behaviour seems unchanged (feeds, drinks and sleeps well) and we haven't noticed any inflammation, but would appreciate the extra pair of eyes.

Our cat always requires full sedation to be even inspected at the vet, which we'd like to avoid as it is quite traumatising for all of us.
What do you think? Do you think this requires a vet intervention? What treatment would you recommend?
